# Default, value and zero initialization mess

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++03, c++98

I am very confused about value- & default- & zero-initialization.
and especially when they kick in for the different standards *C++03* and *C++11* (and *C++14*).

I am quoting and trying to extend a really good answer [Value-/Default-/Zero- Init *C++98* and *C++03*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) here to make it more general as it would help a lot of users if somebody could help fill out the needed gaps to have a good overview about what happens when?

**The full insight by examples in a nutshell:**

Sometimes the memory returned by the new operator will be initialized, and sometimes it won't depending on whether the type you're newing up is a [POD (plain old data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), or if it's a class that contains POD members and is using a compiler-generated default constructor.

- In *C++1998* there are 2 types of initialization: *zero-* and *default-initialization*
- In *C++2003* a 3rd type of initialization, *value-initialization* was added.
- In *C++2011/C++2014* only *list-initialization* was added and the rules for *value-/default-/zero-initialization* changed a bit.

Assume:

```
struct A { int m; };                     
struct B { ~B(); int m; };               
struct C { C() : m(){}; ~C(); int m; };  
struct D { D(){}; int m; };             
struct E { E() = default; int m;}; /** only possible in c++11/14 */  
struct F {F(); int m;};  F::F() = default; /** only possible in c++11/14 */
```

**In a C++98 compiler, the following should occur**:

- `new A`   - indeterminate value (`A` is POD)
- `new A()`- zero-initialize
- `new B`   - default construct (`B::m` is uninitialized, `B` is non-POD)
- `new B()` - default construct (`B::m` is uninitialized)
- `new C`   - default construct (`C::m` is zero-initialized, `C` is non-POD)
- `new C()` - default construct (`C::m` is zero-initialized)
- `new D`   - default construct (`D::m` is uninitialized, `D` is non-POD)
- `new D()` - *default construct?* (`D::m` is uninitialized)

**In a C++03 conformant compiler, things should work like so:**

- `new A`    - indeterminate value (`A` is POD)
- `new A()`  - value-initialize `A`, which is zero-initialization since it's a POD.
- `new B`    - default-initializes (leaves `B::m` uninitialized, `B` is non-POD)
- `new B()`  - value-initializes `B` which zero-initializes all fields since its default ctor is compiler generated as opposed to user-defined.
- `new C`    - default-initializes `C`, which calls the default ctor. (`C::m` is zero-initialized, `C` is non-POD)
- `new C()`  - value-initializes `C`, which calls the default ctor.  (`C::m` is zero-initialized)
- `new D`    - default construct (`D::m` is uninitialized, `D` is non-POD)
- `new D()`  - *value-initializes D?*, which calls the default ctor (`D::m` is uninitialized)

Italic values and ? are uncertainties, please help to correct this :-)

**In a C++11 conformant compiler, things should work like so:**

??? (please help if I start here it will anyway go wrong)

**In a C++14 conformant compiler, things should work like so:**
??? (please help if I start here it will anyway go wrong)
*(Draft based on answer)*

- `new A`    - default-initializes `A`, compiler gen. ctor, (leavs `A::m` uninitialized) (`A` is POD)
- `new A()`  - value-initializes `A`, which is zero-initialization since 2. point in *[dcl.init]/8*
- `new B`   - default-initializes `B`, compiler gen. ctor, (leavs `B::m` uninitialized) (`B` is non-POD)
- `new B()`  - value-initializes `B` which zero-initializes all fields since its default ctor is compiler generated as opposed to user-defined.
- `new C`    - default-initializes `C`, which calls the default ctor. (`C::m` is zero-initialized, `C` is non-POD)
- `new C()`  - value-initializes `C`, which calls the default ctor. (`C::m` is zero-initialized)
- `new D`    - default-initializes `D` (`D::m` is uninitialized, `D` is non-POD)
- `new D()`  - value-initializes `D`, which calls the default ctor (`D::m` is uninitialized)
- `new E`    - default-initializes `E`, which calls the comp. gen. ctor. (`E::m` is uninitialized, E is non-POD)
- `new E()`  - value-initializes `E`, which zero-initializes `E` since 2 point in *[dcl.init]/8* )
- `new F`    - default-initializes `F`, which calls the comp. gen. ctor. (`F::m` is uninitialized, `F` is non-POD)
- `new F()`  - value-initializes `F`, which **default-initializes** `F` since 1. point in *[dcl.init]/8* (`F` ctor function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699720/value-initialization-default-initialization-or-zero-initialization#comment47663175_26699720))

Comment: there's a good explanation of it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's only a difference between C++98 and C++03 in these examples. The issue seems to be described in [N1161](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1998/n1161.pdf) (there are later revisions of that document) and [CWG DR #178](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#178). The *wording* needed to change in C++11 due to new features and a new specification of POD, and it changed again in C++14 due to defects in the C++11 wording, but the effects in these cases are not changed.

Comment: While boring, `struct D { D() {}; int m; };` may be worth including in your list.

Comment: There is a nice an disturbing poster which brings this mess to the point: http://randomcat.org/cpp_initialization/initialization.png

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C++14 specifies initialization of objects created with `new` in [expr.new]/17 ([expr.new]/15 in C++11, and the note wasn't a note but normative text back then):

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that
>   object as follows:
>
> - If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is *default-initialized* (8.5). [ *Note:* If no initialization is
>         performed, the object has an indeterminate value. *— end note* ]
> - Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for *direct-initialization*.

Default-initialization is defined in [dcl.init]/7 (/6 in C++11, and the wording itself has the same effect):

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for `T` is called (and the initialization
>     is ill-formed if `T` has no default constructor or overload resolution
>     (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>     inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is *default-initialized*;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Thus

- `new A` solely causes `A`s default constructor to be called, which does not initialize `m`. Indeterminate value. Should be the same for `new B`.
- `new A()` is interpreted according to [dcl.init]/11 (/10 in C++11):

  > An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be value-initialized.

  And now consider [dcl.init]/8 (/7 in C++11†):

  > To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
  >
  > - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
  >     user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
  > - **if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is
  >     zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
  >     default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default
  >     constructor, the object is default-initialized;**
  > - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
  > - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

  Hence `new A()` will zero-initialize `m`. And this should be equivalent for `A` and `B`.
- `new C` and `new C()` will default-initialize the object again, since the first bullet point from the last quote applies (C has a user-provided default constructor!). But, clearly, now `m` is initialized in the constructor in both cases.

---

† Well, this paragraph has slightly different wording in C++11, which does not alter the result:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a
>     user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for `T`
>     is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible
>     default constructor);
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union
>     class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is
>     zero-initialized and, if `T`’s implicitly-declared default constructor
>     is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if `T` is an array type,
>     then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is
>     zero-initialized.

Comment: ah so you are talking mainly about c++14 and references for c++11 are given in brackets

Comment: @Gabriel Correct. I mean, C++14 is the latest standard, so that is to the fore.

Comment: The annoying thing about trying to trace initialization rules across standards is that a lot of the changes (most? all?) between the published C++14 and C++11 standards happened via DRs, and so are de facto C++11. And then there are also post-C++14 DRs...

Comment: @Columbo I still don't understand why `struct A { int m; };
struct C { C() : m(){};  int m; };`produce different results and what causes m in A to be initialized in the first place. I have opened a dedicated thread for the experiment that i did and i will appreciate your input there to clarify the issue. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290121/c-default-initialization-types

Answer (score 12):

The following answer extends the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/977038 which would serve as a reference for C++ 98 and C++ 03

Quoting the answer

1. In C++1998 there are 2 types of initialization: zero and default
2. In C++2003 a 3rd type of initialization, value initialization was
   added.

C++11 (In reference to n3242)

### Initializers

8.5 Initializers [dcl.init] specifies that a variable POD or non POD can be initialized either as *brace-or-equal-initializer* which can either be  *braced-init-list* or *initializer-clause* aggregately referred to as  *brace-or-equal-initializer* or using *( expression-list )*. Previous to C++11, only *(expression-list)* or *initializer-clause* was supported though *initializer-clause* was more restricted then what we have in C++11. In C++11, *initializer-clause* now supports *braced-init-list* apart from *assignment-expression* as was in C++03. The following grammar summarizes the new supported clause, where the part is bold is newly added in the C++11 standard.

initializer:
    **brace-or-equal-initializer**
    ( expression-list )
**brace-or-equal-initializer:**
    = initializer-clause 
    **braced-init-list** 
initializer-clause:
    assignment-expression 
    **braced-init-list** 
**initializer-list:**
    **initializer-clause ...opt** 
    **initializer-list , initializer-clause ...opt**

**braced-init-list:** 

    **{ initializer-list ,opt }** 

    { }**

### Initialization

Like C++03, C++11 still supports three form of initialize

---

**Note**

> > The part highlighted in bold has been added in C++11 and the one that is striked out has been removed from C++11.

1. #### Initializer Type:8.5.5 [dcl.init] _zero-initialize_

***Performed in the following cases***

- Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized
- If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized
- During *value-initialize*, if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized.

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), ***taken as an integral constant expression***, converted to T;
> - if T is a ***(possibly cv-qualified)*** non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized ***and padding is initialized to zero bits;***
> - if T is a ***(possibly cv-qualified)*** union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero initialized ***and padding is initialized to zero bits;***
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

#### 2. Initializer Type: 8.5.6 [dcl.init] _default-initialize_

Performed in the following cases

- If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
- If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized, except for Objects with static or thread storage duration
- When a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a ***(possibly cv-qualified)***  <strike>non-POD</strike>  class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

---

> **Note** Until C++11, only non-POD class types with automatic storage duration were considered to be default-initialized when no initializer is used.

---

#### 3. Initializer Type: 8.5.7 [dcl.init] _value-initialize_

1. When an object(nameless temporary, named variable, dynamic storage duration or non-static data member)  whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., () or braces {}

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a ***(possibly cv-qualified)*** class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible
>     default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, <strike>then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;</strike> ***then the object is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.***
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

So to summarize

> > **Note** The relevant quotation from the standard is highlighted in **bold**

- new A : default-initializes (leaves A::m uninitialized)
- new A() : Zero-initialize A, as the value initialized candidate does not have a user-provided or deleted default constructor. ***if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.***
- new B : default-initializes (leaves B::m uninitialized)
- new B() : value-initializes B which zero-initializes all fields; ***if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called***
- new C : default-initializes C, which calls the default ctor. ***if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called***, Moreover If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized
- new C() : value-initializes C, which calls the default ctor. ***if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called.*** Moreover, ***An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized***

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that in C++11, everything mentioned in the question under C++14 is correct, at least as per compiler implementations.

In order to verify this, I added the following code to my [test suite](https://github.com/vgc/vgc/blob/master/libs/vgc/core/tests/test_zero.cpp). I tested with `-std=c++11 -O3` in GCC 7.4.0, GCC 5.4.0, Clang 10.0.1, and VS 2017, and all the tests below pass.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <memory>

struct A { int m;                    };
struct B { int m;            ~B(){}; };
struct C { int m; C():m(){}; ~C(){}; };
struct D { int m; D(){};             };
struct E { int m; E() = default;     };
struct F { int m; F();               }; F::F() = default;

// We use this macro to fill stack memory with something else than 0.
// Subsequent calls to EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0) are undefined behavior in theory, but
// pass in practice, and help illustrate that `a.m` is indeed not initialized
// to zero. Note that we initially tried the more aggressive test
// EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 42), but it didn't pass on all compilers (a.m wasn't equal to
// 42, but was still equal to some garbage value, not zero).
//
// Update 2020-12-14: Even the less aggressive EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0) fails in some
// machines, so we comment them out. But this change in behavior does illustrate
// that, in fact, the behavior was undefined.
//
#define FILL { int m = 42; EXPECT_EQ(m, 42); }

// We use this macro to fill heap memory with something else than 0, before
// doing a placement new at that same exact location. Subsequent calls to
// EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42) are undefined behavior in theory, but pass in practice,
// and help illustrate that `a->m` is indeed not initialized to zero.
//
#define FILLH(b) std::unique_ptr<int> bp(new int(42)); int* b = bp.get(); EXPECT_EQ(*b, 42)

TEST(TestZero, StackDefaultInitialization)
{
    //{ FILL; A a; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    //{ FILL; B a; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    { FILL; C a; EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    //{ FILL; D a; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    //{ FILL; E a; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    //{ FILL; F a; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
}

TEST(TestZero, StackValueInitialization)
{
    { FILL; A a = A(); EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    { FILL; B a = B(); EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    { FILL; C a = C(); EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    //{ FILL; D a = D(); EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    { FILL; E a = E(); EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    //{ FILL; F a = F(); EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
}

TEST(TestZero, StackListInitialization)
{
    { FILL; A a{}; EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    { FILL; B a{}; EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    { FILL; C a{}; EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    //{ FILL; D a{}; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
    { FILL; E a{}; EXPECT_EQ(a.m, 0); }
    //{ FILL; F a{}; EXPECT_NE(a.m, 0); } // UB!
}

TEST(TestZero, HeapDefaultInitialization)
{
    { FILLH(b); A* a = new (b) A; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); B* a = new (b) B; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); C* a = new (b) C; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); D* a = new (b) D; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); E* a = new (b) E; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); F* a = new (b) F; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
}

TEST(TestZero, HeapValueInitialization)
{
    { FILLH(b); A* a = new (b) A(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); B* a = new (b) B(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); C* a = new (b) C(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); D* a = new (b) D(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); E* a = new (b) E(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); F* a = new (b) F(); EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
}

TEST(TestZero, HeapListInitialization)
{
    { FILLH(b); A* a = new (b) A{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); B* a = new (b) B{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); C* a = new (b) C{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); D* a = new (b) D{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
    { FILLH(b); E* a = new (b) E{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 0);  }
    { FILLH(b); F* a = new (b) F{}; EXPECT_EQ(a->m, 42); } // ~UB
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The places where `UB!` is mentioned are undefined behavior, and the actual behavior is likely to depend on many factors (`a.m` might be equal to 42, 0, or some other garbage). The places where `~UB` is mentioned are also undefined behavior in theory, but in practice, due the use of a placement new, it's very unlikely than `a->m` will be equal to anything else than 42.

Comment: Some tests seem to fail for me even using GCC7.4: https://godbolt.org/z/PocEGz6sq... could be that the GTest version matters? This is weird, because the code seems to be part of your test suite on GitHub, where the test still passes (or at least did 5 months ago?)

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Thanks for the heads up. I'll be back to coding on this soon so I'll see if the tests still pass. I remember some tests didn't pass on some platforms and I had to make changes, not sure if it was before or after this SO post. Note that I'm now using C++17, so results might differ too because of this.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka I added a GitHub issue to track this, if you're interested: https://github.com/vgc/vgc/issues/566

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka I just had some time to look at this. You're right, the tests marked "UB!" do fail in some machines/compilers. And in fact, I had already commented them out in my production codebase back in 2020-12-14 (https://github.com/vgc/vgc/commit/1d3f492e6), reason why my tests pass. The morale of the story is: those are definitely undefined behavior, so, well, the behavior is undefined. The value is not supposed to be zero-initialized, but it may happen to be zero anyway by "chance" or other factors.