# C++ default initialization types

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, default-value

Why those two scenarios (the initialization of A and of C ) produce different default initialization results in C++ 14? 
I can't understand the result based on the default initialization rules in cppreference.com

```
struct A { int m; };
struct C { C() : m(){};  int m; };  

int main() {
  A *a, *d;
  A b;
  A c{};
  a=new A();
  d=new A;
  cout<<a->m<<endl;
  cout<<d->m<<endl;
  cout<<b.m<<endl;
  cout<<c.m<<endl;
  cout<<"--------------------"<<endl;
  C *a1, *d1;
  C b1;
  C c1{};   
  a1=new C();
  d1=new C;
  cout<<a1->m<<endl;
  cout<<d1->m<<endl;
  cout<<b1.m<<endl;
  cout<<c1.m<<endl;
 }
```

Output:

```
(Scenario 1)
    0 
    -1771317376
    -1771317376
    0
    --------------------
(Scenario 2)
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

The post that tries to explain this (but it's not clear to me yet why the difference in the results and what causes m to be initialized in each scenario): [Default, value and zero initialization mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765961/default-value-and-zero-initialization-mess)

Comment: Could you provide the cppreference.com page you're referencing?

Comment: your naming is so confusing

Comment: @JohnathanGross i have updated the original post with a link to a post that quotes the relevant parts from cppreference

Comment: a and c are examples of value initialization (which zeroes everything out). b and d sre examples of default initialization, which does nothing for trivially constructible types such as A

Answer (score -1):

`A` has no user defined constructors, so a default constructor was generated. `C` has a user defined constructor, so there is no guarantee that a default constructor was generated, especially since the user defined constructor overloads the default constructor. It is almost certain that every construction of C used the user defined constructor.

In the user defined constructor for `C` uses an initialization list to value initialize `C::m`. When `C::m` is initialized, it is value initialized, which includes a zero initialization.

`new A;` and `A b;` are default initializations. This does not set assign any values to their members. What value is stored in `A::m` is undefined behavior.

`new A();` and `A c{};` are value initializations. As part of the value initialization, it performs a zero initialization.

Comment: "C has a user defined constructor, so there is no guarantee that a default constructor was generated". Actually there is a guarantee that the default constructor will not be implicitly generated.