# How temporary objects behave in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object

When I tried to run the code below, I got totally confused..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{
    public:
    int num = 30;

    int yourAge ;

    void set(){
        yourAge = (test().num)*2; 
    }
};

int main(){
    test obj;


    cout << test().yourAge << endl; // i was expecting garbage but giving me 0
    cout << obj.yourAge << endl;    // ya! garbage it is, in this case

    ///// now/////

    test().set()
    cout << test().yourAge << endl;  // Iwas expecting 60 but giving me againg 0

    cout << obj.yourAge << endl;  // I was expecting garbage but giving me 0;



    return 0;
}
```

I have described my problems in the code, but why they are giving unexpected results. Why that is happening? Does it because I am using temporary nameless object or something else is happening? I will be thankful for your answers.

Comment: Stop right there.  You are designing tests based on undefined behavior and expecting some kind of predictable result.

Comment: When you access the value of an object that is uninitialized, don't expect any sensible behavior.

Comment: Sometimes zero is garbage. Sometimes garbage is zero.

Comment: I don't think you'll gain much from digging this any further.

Comment: Undefined behavior is not required to behave.

Comment: When you call `test().set()` and then expect that `test().yourAge` changed somehow is wrong because in each case new temporary object is created and destroyed at end of expression. There is no connection whatsoever between different temporaries except for case with static variables.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765961/default-value-and-zero-initialization-mess. Behaviors can be different depending on how you initialize the object and which c++ standard you are using.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere you use `test()` you build a temporary object of type `test` which is initialised as specified in your class.
This initialisation is `30` for the `num` member but could be anything for the `yourAge` member (except with static storage but it's another topic).

Then any expression like `test().yourAge` builds a temporary object, retrieves its `yourAge` member which value is **uninitialised** (it could be -17, 0 or whatever) and lets this temporary object disappear.

When calling `test().set()` you create a temporary object, initialise its `yourName` member thanks to the `set()` method but let this object disappear without using it!
Any subsequent `test()` expression is a new temporary object with no reason to be related to the one on which `set()` was called.

The case of `obj` is similar except that this object will last as long as the block containing it (the `main()` function here) is executed.
Its `yourAge` member is never initialised, so it could contain anything; if you ever used `obj.set()` then, after that call you could have expected to find something relevant in `obj.yourAge`.