# Is there an example of specializing std::allocator_traits::construct?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have the task of porting some code to c++20. Part of it is an templated allocator that handles some of the odd needs or Microsoft COM objects so we can use them in vectors. In part, it allocates/deallocates memory via CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree
It also provides specializations of construct and destroy which have gone way in c++20.

For Example:

```
// VARIANT

inline void CnvCoTaskAlloc<VARIANT>::construct(VARIANT* p, const VARIANT& val){
    ::VariantCopy( p, const_cast<VARIANT*>( &val ) );
}

inline void CnvCoTaskAlloc<VARIANT>::destroy(VARIANT* p){
    ::VariantClear( p );
}
```

I am having a hard time working out how to migrate this code to c++20. If I could find an example of doing something similar that implements construct, I am pretty sure it would be obvious.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customizing std::allocator\_traits::construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985619/customizing-stdallocator-traitsconstruct)

Comment: this confused me as well. it is not that the specialization has gone way, but rather that the specialization is not necessary to fulfill the concept of Allocator. You can still customize construct and destruct as a member. do not specialize the trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard has the following to say about specializing standard library templates ([namespace.std]/2):

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

The standard specifies the following behaviour for `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` ([allocator.traits.members]/5):

> ```
> template<class T, class... Args>
>   static constexpr void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, invokes `construct_at(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

So, if you choose to specialize `std::allocator_traits<MyAlloc>::construct`, it must do basically the same thing as the primary template: it will call `MyAlloc::construct` if possible, otherwise `construct_at`.

This suggests that specializing `std::allocator_traits` is generally not what you want to do. Instead, just like pre-C++20, you just need to make sure that `MyAlloc::construct` contains the logic that you want. If you want the default, you can even omit `MyAlloc::construct` entirely, and `std::allocator_traits` will take care of it.

Comment: Brian, This pointed me at the underlying issue. My brain misparsed the actual error and missed that we were using a template elsewhere that depended on  std::allocator::construct. Changing that to use allocator::traits let it pick up the implementation for our custom one. Thanks.