# Does the defaulted default constructor initialize variables to zero?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14

I'm updating a class to C++14, and trying to figure out the simplest way to initialize all of the instance variables to zero on construction. Here's what I have so far:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int var;
    float* ptr;
    double array[3];
    MyStruct data;
    unique_ptr<MyStruct> smart_ptr;

    MyClass() = default;
    ~MyClass() = default;
}
```

Is setting the constructor to `default` the equivalent of doing:

```
MyClass() : var{}, ptr{}, array{}, data{}, smart_ptr{} {}
```

... or do I need to init each variable? (I've tried both in Visual Studio and I get zeros either way, but I'm not sure if that's luck or not.)

I'm instancing the class without brackets: `MyClass obj;`

Comment: Man, I was going to give you smug answer but now I'm not certain. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types

Comment: Hahah :) I know, right! I actually saw that post, but it was really this comment that left me feeling uncertain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types#comment36188015_2418195. So it zero-inits if you don't have a constructor at all, and call `MyClass instance()` with brackets? :|

Comment: Logically, setting a constructor to `default` would be expected to default-initialise members.    Default-initialisation is not always equivalent to zero-initialisation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is setting the constructor to default the equivalent of doing:
>
> ```
> MyClass() : var{}, ptr{}, array{}, data{}, smart_ptr{} {}
> ```

No. It is not.

---

The line

```
MyClass() = default;
```

is more akin to but not exactly equivalent to:

```
 MyClass() {}
```

In either case, using

```
 MyClass obj;
```

results in a default-initialized object whose members are default initialized.

However, the difference between them when using

```
 MyClass obj{};
```

is that `obj` will be zero-initialized with the defaulted default constructor while it will be still default initialized with the user provided default constructor.

Comment: typo: int{} should be var{}

Comment: Fixed, thanks! I appreciate your answer, too. Am I right in thinking that `MyClass() {}` is a user-provided constructor, whereas `MyClass = default;` is a default constructor, so it would be zero-initialized in some circumstances? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699720/value-initialization-default-initialization-or-zero-initialization

Comment: @ChrisNolet "default constructor" means a constructor that can be called with no arguments

Comment: Ahh, right you are, sorry. I meant defaulted constructor.

Answer (score 4):

To make all of your variables zero-initialized on construction, even if the creator did not request it, one way is:

```
struct MyClassMembers
{
    int var;
    float* ptr;
    double array[3];
    MyStruct data;
    unique_ptr<MyStruct> smart_ptr;
};

struct MyClass : MyClassMembers
{
    MyClass(): MyClassMembers{} {}
};
```

Then `MyClass m;` will use `MyClassMembers{}` to initialize the members.

Comment: unless one of the members has a non defaulted default constructor, as detailed in R Sahu's answer

Comment: @Danra I'm assuming that OP is fine with a member using its own constructor as defined

Answer (score 1):

It is worth clarifying a few points. For a class with members as follows,

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int var;
  float* ptr;
  double array[3];
  MyStruct data;
  unique_ptr<MyStruct> smart_ptr;
  ...
}
```

A default constructor defined by the user as follows,

```
MyClass() : var{}, ptr{}, array{}, data{}, smart_ptr{} {}
```

will lead to [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of the member variables. If a member variable is a class type then its value initialization happens under certain conditions as described in that link.

While defining an object with or without braces (`MyClass obj{};` or `MyClass obj;`), this default constructor will lead to value initialization of the class members.

Suppose, `MyClass` has a default constructor in one of the following forms:

```
MyClass() {};
MyClass() = default;
```

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-syntax-default-in-c11) about further information on these two forms for the default constructor.) As far as defining and initializing objects of `MyClass` is concerned, `MyClass() {};` leads to default initialization, while `MyClass() = default;` leads to value initialization when defining an object with braces (`MyClass obj{};`). This is because `MyClass() {};` is a user defined default constructor with an empty initialization list and an empty body, which will lead to default initialization of the members. On the other hand, `MyClass() = default;` leads to a compiler defined default constructor, which will correctly lead to value initialization when defining an object with braces. See [here](https://accu.org/journals/overload/25/139/brand_2379/) about how even the `= default;` could go wrong.